# How to import jsrsasign module in the background of a Chrome Extension using Manifest V3?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I want to import `jsrsasign-all-min.js` library to parse JWT tokens after login with Google OAuth2 in the Extension I am developing.

The problem I have is that I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

I supposed this comes up because this library is meant to run in the front-end and the `background.js` is not exactly that.

This is my `manifest.json` file:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Reputation System",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "key": "xxx",
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js",
        "type": "module"
    },
    "action": {
        "default_title": "Reputation System"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "identity",
        "scripting"
    ],
    "oauth2": {
        "client_id": "xxx",
        "scopes": [
          "openid"
        ]
    }
}
```

I am importing the library like this in my `background.js`:

```
import { KJUR } from "./jsrsasign-all-min.js";
```

And trying to use this function:

```
const user_info = KJUR.jws.JWS.readSafeJSONString(b64utoutf8(id_token.split(".")[1]));
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. This library is not a module, it simply declares a bunch of global `var`, so you can't use the `import` statement because these variables won't be accessible from outside the script.
2. This library is not worker-friendly and it mistakenly uses `window` to access the global namespace.

Solution:

1. remove `"type": "module"` from manifest.json - this will enable importScripts.
2. change background.js to this:

```js
self.window = self;
importScripts('./jsrsasign-all-min.js');
// now you can use KJUR and other globals vars
```

Alternative solutions:

- use a different library that's worker-friendly and can be imported
- use a build system that allows *shimming* module globals
- manually build the library to produce a proper module

Comment: What an amazing answer! I hope I could give you more than an "accept" and a "thumbs up" :D