# (Chrome Extension) Getting the metadata from a music file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webpack, google-chrome-extension, plugins

I've been stuck on this for days, and I still haven't found a solution. Basically I'm creating a music player Chrome extension, and what I need is the metadata for a music file so that I can get the song's artist (as well as icon/picture).

I've tried and implemented 'Chrome Extension Cli' (https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-extension-cli) into my project for the sake of webpacks, but every time I attempt to use something like 'jsmediatags' for example, I get met with errors upon errors.

Does anyone know how to do achieve this through a Chrome Extension?

Comment: It depends on where you want to do it. If it's in service worker, you need to find a library that can run in a service worker i.e. it shouldn't depend on `window` in the best case or it should work if you prepend it with `self.window = self` ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73644394)).

Comment: There's no need for a library, actually: [Read id3 v2.4 tags with native Chrome Javascript/FileReader/DataView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20212560)

Comment: wOxxOm Thanks, but with your 2nd comment, it does need a library. Fortunately, I have implemented a webpack, but now using jDataView, I'm getting an error that says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'Buffer' in undefined". Also, I'm doing it in the main javaScript file (popup.js), not in the background

Comment: Ahh, yes, I see it now, apologies. Tried it, and it did work. Thanks for the help :)